# Referencing resources in node_modules folder

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, node-modules

I am currently in the process of writing my first Node.js app. I recently installed bootstrap via the npm (following instructions on [bootstrap's web site](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)) and was wondering the "standard" way of referencing the bootstap.min.css (and other files of interest). It is best to use grunt/gulp to copy (bundle and minify) the resources I need into my project structure?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to copy with the node_modules bootstrap resources with a simple Grunt task:

```
copy: {
    bootstrapSrcCss: {
      src: "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
      dest: "./public/src/css/bootstrap.css"
    },
    bootstrapSrcJs: {
      src: "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
      dest: "./public/src/js/bootstrap.js"
    }
}
```

Using grunt plug-in: grunt-contrib-copy

Answer (score -1):

As explained in [This Blog Post](http://www.tagwith.com/question_238400_how-to-include-scripts-located-inside-the-node-modules-folder), you can create a "Static Route" instead of exposing the node_modules structure totally.

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/'));
```

But that may not be the best method.  It seems that packages that come with resources also come with Grunt files as well.

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: This will expose an unknown collection of files publicly - a collection of unknown files which will change in unpredictable ways as the library versions forward. It's a low security risk in this exact bootstrap example, but a risk nonetheless, and a greater risk as you use this pattern with more and more libraries.